# Numpy log() function devide by zero

Tags: pandas

I try to do this

```
df['VAL'] = np.where((df['FIRST'] + df['SECOND']).gt(0), np.log(df['FIRST'] + df['SECOND']), np.nan)
```

And get `devide by zero encountered in log`. Why condition returns `True` and dont set `None` to value?

Comment: I don't know what you want to use  `pd['VAL']` for but from my experience it is a good solution to calculate the log of the variable plus one to avoid the issue you're facing and not loosing to many data points

Comment: @TiTo Sorry pd is just df(dataframe)